# Import Excel Workbook contents into a data table (Visual Basic .NET)

Tags: vb.net, excel, datatable

I am trying to perform an operation that might be quite simple really, but since I don't have experience in doing this prior to this point, I may be missing something.

I have an Excel file that needs to be imported into a data table in Visual Basic (.NET 2010). Now, I am trying to import as a data-table, so that I can have the data flexible and ready to be used as and how I wanted to.

The Excel spreadsheet doesn't exactly have the most promising and worthwhile formatting, which makes this situation a tad-bit difficult. The column headers are not on the first row itself, but are on the 5th row and this might not always be the case. The column headers might even end up on the 10th row or even the first row - Any help on this would be great too.

The name of the worksheet can also be different, since I don't have any control over the end users that will be using the application. Any suggestions or code-help here please?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to deal with the formatting issues to have true success. A consistent input is the only way to secure consistent output. Otherwise, you will need to build an interface that allows your users to map fields as they go.

Once you have that taken care of, I suggest using the OpenXML SDK to import your values ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh298534.aspx )